# DateTime createfromformat doe not work

Tags: php, datetime

I create php DateTime with a string like that:

```
$time = '19:14, 9 June 2016 (UTC)';
\DateTime($time);
```

That works very well, but because the time comes from an external ressource, its sometime non-valid like

```
$time = '19:14, 9 oktober 2016 (UTC)'; #oktober instead of october
```

Then DateTime ends with a fatal error. To prevent this, I wanted to check if the timestring is valid before using DateTime. The only solution I found is, to use `DateTime::createFromFormat()`. I dont like this solution very much, because in new `DateTime()` I can use several formats, in `createFromFormat` I have to check every format.

However, second problem is, that `createFromFormat` doesn't even recognize my correct timestring:

```
$time = '19:14, 9 June 2016 (UTC)';
$valid = \DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i, d F Y (e)', $time);
```

returns false. But using the format on date() it returns exactly the same string:

```
echo date('H:i, d F Y (e)', time());
#12:14, 22 June 2016 (UTC)
```

Comment: Is your region GMT+7?

Comment: why? script timezone is utc

Comment: Without the timezone it works, but why it doesn't work with the timezone is something which needs to be investigated...

Comment: If you remove the braces `( )` it works, probably that's why it fails.

Comment: If you remove the trailing bracket from your format string it should work correctly - it's a bug in the DateTime parser. See https://eval.in/593559

Comment: works, great! thanks

Answer (score 2):

Charlotte Dunois and iainn answered it in the comments. It is a bug and you have to remove the brackets surrounding the timezone (e), more precise just the closing bracket.

```
$time = '19:14, 9 June 2016 (UTC)';
$valid = \DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i, d F Y (e)', $time); #does not work
$valid = \DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i, d F Y e', $time); #works
$valid = \DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i, d F Y (e', $time); #works
```